# flexslider makes iPad crash

Tags: javascript, ipad, flexslider

I have an issue with the flexslider : everything is working well on desktop and mobiles, but on iPad the flexslider makes the browser crash... I tested on Safari and Chrome on iPad, same issue on both browsers... The problem occures when there's more than 5 or 6 slides, under 5 slides everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests and tries, I figured out the issue : it seems that when there are many slides, the "fade" flexslider animation consumes lot of memory and makes the iPad crash.

To fix the issue, I defined on script.js "slide" for the animation effect for my slider, and it worked.